# Registering Events in a manager type class

Tags: c#, events

I'm still a beginner at this stuff, and I am trying to get a better understanding of Events and how to use them properly.

I have a manager class that has a container that stores a bunch of objects; each object has an event (essentially saying it is done doing the thing it does).  I would like the manager class to subscribe to the event and remove the object from the container when the event fires.

When you register with an object's event, does it register with all instances of that object, or is it instance specific?

So here is kind of what I am looking at:

```
 class MyManager
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyObject> m_myObjectCollection;

    public MyManager()
    {
        m_myObjectCollection = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyObject>();


    }


    private void RemoveObject(MyObject myObject)
    {
        //remove object from collection
    }
}


class MyObject
{      

    public delegate void MyObjectFinished_EventHandler(object source, EventArgs e);

    public event MyObjectFinished_EventHandler OnFinished;

    public MyObject()
    {

        this.OnFinished += new MyObjectFinished_EventHandler(MyObject_OnFinished);

    }

    private void MyObject_OnFinished(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do some clean up stuff
    }

    private void DoStuff()
    {
        //do stuff until finished
        OnFinished(this, new EventArgs());
    }
```

Is it enough to have the manager class create an instance of the MyObject and then register with that object's event?  That doesn't seem right to me; my instinct says that I would just be registered for the event of that one object, and not all instances of that object type.

Or is it that I need to register with each MyObject as I add it to the collection, and then unregister with it when it is removed?

Or is there a better way of handling this altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the answer already: you need to register a function to handle the MyObjectFinished_EventHandler for each instance of MyObject that you create in MyManager:

```
private void CreateObjects()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        MyObject o = new MyObject();
        o.OnFinished += OnMyObjectFinished;
        m_myObjectCollection.TryAdd(i.ToString(), o);
    }
}
```

The handler would look like this:

```
private void OnMyObjectFinished(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    MyObject o = (MyObject)source;
    RemoveObject(o);
}
```

As you can see, you cast source to a MyObject reference and then use it to do the needful.

Edit: I wanted to clarify one more thing: you're calling the cleanup function in the MyObject class by subscribing to the OnFinished event; that works, but the simpler thing would be to just call the cleanup function directly in DoStuff():

```
public delegate void MyObjectFinished_EventHandler(object source, EventArgs e);

    public event MyObjectFinished_EventHandler OnFinished;

    public MyObject()
    {
    }

    private void Finished()
    {
        //do some clean up stuff
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        //do stuff until finished
        Finished();
        OnFinished(this, new EventArgs());
    }
```

Events are typically used to signal someone else (another object) that something has happened.

Comment: I suspected that was the case; thank you very much for taking the time to clarify that for me!

Answer (score 0):

> When you register with an object's event, does it register with all
>   instances of that object, or is it instance specific?

Yes, In your case you are wiring the Event to every object instance inside the constructor.so ,the event will be available to all instances.

A new Event/Delegate object is created for every instance of the object.

> Or is it that I need to register with each MyObject as I add it to the
>   collection, and then unregister with it when it is removed?

You are already doing this by wiring the event to the newly created object instance.
You could have a method to manually remove the event from each object or you could just leave it to the Garbage collector to do the job for you.The event objects will live as long as the object using it is still on memory or not garbage collected.